# R: Forcing Plotly to Display Graphs

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

Recently, I noticed that whenever I make a graph in plotly - when I try to call the object to view it locally within the viewer, the graph will not open.

However, if I save the graph using HTMLWIDGETS as an HTML file, I can then view the same graph.

**Is there some way to force R to display a plotly plot in the viewer?**

For example, is there some command I can enter to "force" R into displaying the graph?

Thanks!

Note: I am using R version 3.5.2

Comment: It is probably a good idea to update to the latest versions of R, RStudio and the plotly package (and its dependencies). Depending on the versions you are currently using one or more components might not want to play with each other anymore right now...